# cypher -- missing one possible path

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm new with cypher expression.
And I have this database

```
CREATE
  (a:City {name: 'A'}),
  (b:City {name: 'B'}),
  (c:City {name: 'C'}),
  (d:City {name: 'D'}),
  (e:City {name: 'E'}),
  (a)-[:HAS_RAIL_ROAD_TO {distance : 5 }]->(b),
  (b)-[:HAS_RAIL_ROAD_TO {distance : 4 }]->(c),
  (c)-[:HAS_RAIL_ROAD_TO {distance : 8 }]->(d),
  (d)-[:HAS_RAIL_ROAD_TO {distance : 8 }]->(c),
  (d)-[:HAS_RAIL_ROAD_TO {distance : 6 }]->(e),
  (a)-[:HAS_RAIL_ROAD_TO {distance : 5 }]->(d),
  (c)-[:HAS_RAIL_ROAD_TO {distance : 2 }]->(e),
  (e)-[:HAS_RAIL_ROAD_TO {distance : 3 }]->(b),
  (a)-[:HAS_RAIL_ROAD_TO {distance : 7 }]->(e)
```

When I execute

```
  MATCH(:City { name: 'A' })-[r:HAS_RAIL_ROAD_TO*4]->(:City { name: 'C' })
  return count(r)
```

**I was expecting 3 as result:**

`(A, B, C,D, C); (A, D, C, D, C); (A, D, E, B, C)`.

**But the result given is 2**

I think in the second case `(A, D, C, D, C)` it is not coming back to D.

What do you think is the reason for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has to do with the [uniqueness behavior in Cypher traversals](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/introduction/uniqueness/), which ensures that a relationship can only be traversed once per path per MATCH pattern.

`(A, D, C, D, C)` will not work because there are only two relationships between D and C, and the `D, C, D` part traversed both of them, leaving no other relationships available to traverse again back from D to C.

This uniqueness behavior is useful for most cases, and also prevents any kind of infinite loop problems with unbounded variable-length patterns.

If you do need to consider reusing relationships in your paths, you'll need a different approach, one that lets you change the uniqueness behavior during traversal.

You can use [path expander procs](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#path-expander) from [APOC Procedures](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/) to change the uniqueness and expand out, but PLEASE make sure to set an upper bound (via the `maxLevel` config property) otherwise you risk an infinite loop traversal which will likely blow the heap.

```
MATCH (start:City { name: 'A' }), (end:City { name: 'C' })
CALL apoc.path.expandConfig(start, {endNodes:[end], minLevel:4, maxLevel:4, relationshipFilter:'HAS_RAIL_ROAD_TO>', uniqueness:'NONE'}) YIELD path
RETURN [node in nodes(path) | node.name] as path
```